# Generalize Update query in Sql for date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a SQL Server table named `Pedidos` with this structure:

[image]

Every month (at its last days) I have to run this queries:

```
UPDATE PEDIDOS
SET PedFchAct = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-08-28 00:00:00', 102), 
    PrgFchAct = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-08-28 00:00:00', 102)
WHERE     
    (PedFecCap = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-09-01 00:00:00', 102))

UPDATE PEDIDOS
SET PedFchAct = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-08-29 00:00:00', 102), 
    PrgFchAct = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-08-29 00:00:00', 102)
WHERE (PedFecCap = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-09-02 00:00:00', 102))

UPDATE PEDIDOS
SET PedFchAct = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-08-30 00:00:00', 102), 
    PrgFchAct = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-08-30 00:00:00', 102)
WHERE 
    (PedFecCap > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-09-02 00:00:00', 102)) 
    AND (PedFecCap <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-09-30 00:00:00', 102))
```

The idea is the following, I have to segment the registers by `PedFecCap` in three.

Filter dates would be:

- PedFecCap = 1 / nextmonth / 2017
- PedFecCap = 2 / nextmonth / 2017, and
- lastdayOfnextMonth / nextmonth / 2017 <= PedFecCap > 2 / nextmonth / 2017

Then I have to update PedFchAct and PrgFchAct, and set three different dates of current month for each filtered segment. For example:

For **PedFecCap**=1/nextmonth/2017, PedFchAct and PrgFchAct= 28/currentmonth/2017

For **PedFecCap**=2/nextmonth/2017, PedFchAct and PrgFchAct= 29/currentmonth/2017

For lastdayOfnextMonth/nextmonth/2017<=**PedFecCap**>2/nextmonth/2017, PedFchAct and PrgFchAct= 30/currentmonth/2017

I need to generalize this query and eliminate fixed values so every month I only run the script and not rewrite the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data

```
pedfeccap               pedfchaact  prgfchact
2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-07-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-07-03 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-07-28 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-07-29 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-07-30 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-07-31 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-08-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-08-03 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-08-28 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-08-29 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-08-30 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-09-01 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-09-03 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-09-27 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-09-29 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
2017-09-30 00:00:00.000 NULL        NULL
```

You can use the first day and last day computation for each date

```
UPDATE pedidos
   SET pedfchaact = CASE WHEN pedfeccap = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, pedfeccap), 0)
                         THEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, pedfeccap) -2, 0) + 27
                         WHEN pedfeccap = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, pedfeccap), 0) + 1
                         THEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, pedfeccap) -2, 0) + 28
                         ELSE DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, pedfeccap) -2, 0) + 29
                     END,
       prgfchact = CASE WHEN pedfeccap = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, pedfeccap), 0)
                        THEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, pedfeccap) -2, 0) + 27
                        WHEN pedfeccap = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, pedfeccap), 0) + 1
                        THEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, pedfeccap) -2, 0) + 28
                        ELSE DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, pedfeccap) -2, 0) + 29
                    END;
```

Result

```
pedfeccap               pedfchaact              prgfchact
2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 2017-06-28 00:00:00.000 2017-06-28 00:00:00.000
2017-07-02 00:00:00.000 2017-06-29 00:00:00.000 2017-06-29 00:00:00.000
2017-07-03 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000
2017-07-28 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000
2017-07-29 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000
2017-07-30 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000
2017-07-31 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000 2017-06-30 00:00:00.000
2017-08-01 00:00:00.000 2017-07-28 00:00:00.000 2017-07-28 00:00:00.000
2017-08-02 00:00:00.000 2017-07-29 00:00:00.000 2017-07-29 00:00:00.000
2017-08-03 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000
2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000
2017-08-28 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000
2017-08-29 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000
2017-08-30 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000
2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000 2017-07-30 00:00:00.000
2017-09-01 00:00:00.000 2017-08-28 00:00:00.000 2017-08-28 00:00:00.000
2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 2017-08-29 00:00:00.000 2017-08-29 00:00:00.000
2017-09-03 00:00:00.000 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000
2017-09-27 00:00:00.000 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000
2017-09-28 00:00:00.000 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000
2017-09-29 00:00:00.000 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000
2017-09-30 00:00:00.000 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000 2017-08-30 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Please read carefully my question. pedfchaact and prgfchact groups (which are updated in three segments) only difers in the day. The month is the same, current month.

Comment: please see the updated SQL UPDATE statement and result

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE PEDIDOS
SET
    PedFchAct = CASE
                    WHEN PedFecCap = '2017-09-01' THEN '2017-08-28'
                    WHEN PedFecCap = '2017-09-02' THEN '2017-08-29'
                    ELSE '2017-08-30'
                END,
    PrgFchAct = CASE
                    WHEN PedFecCap = '2017-09-01' THEN '2017-08-28'
                    WHEN PedFecCap = '2017-09-02' THEN '2017-08-29'
                    ELSE '2017-08-30'
                END
WHERE
    PedFecCap BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2017-09-30'
```

Comment: That's perfect for this month case, but next month it will change, and instead of having 08 and 09 (August and September) would be 09 and 10 respectively. that's the point of generalizing.